# Execute CMD in remote desktop and receive output

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, wmi, remote-access

I'm trying to execute a command in a remote desktop cmd. I have the IP, username and password of that remote desktop and I can access it through the remote desktop application. I have tried this code to send the 'uxm getrole' command to the remote cmd but I can't get the output of the cmd. I'm converting this python file into executable with pyinstaller because the computer that runs this code can't have python installed, I don't know if could be an issue with that.

```
import wmi
from socket import *

ip = ip_address
username = 'username'
password = 'password'

try:
    print("Establishing connection to %s" %ip)
    connection = wmi.WMI(ip, user=username, password=password)
    print("Connection established")
    res = connection.Win32_Process.Create(CommandLine='cmd.exe /c uxm getrole')
    print(res)
except wmi.x_wmi:
    print("Your Username and Password of "+getfqdn(ip)+" are wrong.")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Is there a way to receive the output from the remote cmd without having to create a SSH in the remote desktop? Maybe I should use subprocess library when I open the connection? But I don't know how to do it.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you getting any errors with this code? can you post the error? Are you able to establish a connection like this? Have you already checked if your Remote PC is able to accept remote scripts? sometimes that's disabled and that's the reason why one can't execute scripts

Comment: I get the "Establishing connection" message and then the "Connection established" message so I guess there is no error. But when I try to print the result I only get "(12324, 0)" the first number change everytime that I execute the code but the second number seems to be the return code and if it's 0 so I'm guessing there is no error. But I want to receive the output of the cmd, I should get a string that say 'main' or 'auxiliary'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not sticking with python. You can use `PsExec` to execute remote commands.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec

Comment: I have to use python, maybe can I run a PsExec command with the subprocess library in python?

Comment: Yes, It can be done using subprocess

Answer (score 0):

I could finally do what I wanted with the PsExec and the subprocess module. I need to have the PsExec.exe file in the same folder than my python file and the code would be something like this:

```
import subprocess as sp
try:
    res = sp.run(r'psexec -i \\IP_ADDRESS -u DOMAIN\user -p password cmd /c command', check=True, capture_output=True, shell=True)
    print(res.stdout)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Thank you all for yours answers.